# UltraSPARC Serial Port and Required Cable

Tags: modem, serial, cable, ultrasparc

I have two large SPARC machines and no monitor cable that plugs into them. So I'm trying to get a serial connection to them through null modem cables. However, there doesn't appear to be such ports on the back of these computers. I have taken pictures of the backs of these computers. Can any of these ports can be used for a serial connection? If so, what cables do I need?

[image: First Server]
[image: Second Server]

Update: The serial port on the first server worked once I hooked it up with converter cable and finally to a Tripp Lite USB to Serial Adapter. I don't have the model numbers since these were just leftover scrap machines for a performance measurement lab.

Update 2: When I used a gender-changer on the bottom of the two DB25 connectors, the serial console showed up.

Comment: The serial port is **labeled** on the first server. It's a standard DB25m port. The second doesn't appear to have a serial port, at least from that picture.

Comment: What model SPARC systems are these? (It's important. Sparc hardware has a BUNCH of different serial port configurations!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume these are Sun systems.  As I mentioned in my comment [there are a BUNCH of serial port types on Sun hardware](http://www.sunhelp.org/unix-serial-port-resources/serial-pinouts/). Some of these are REALLY freaky!

As Chris pointed out, your first server's serial port is labeled.
You don't tell us what model this is, but since it's just one port I'm betting it's a combined (A+B) port [like the SLC has](http://www.sunhelp.org/unix-serial-port-resources/serial-pinouts/#elc.slc.link).
If you plug a standard 25-pin serial connector into that it should Just Work (you'll get port A - the default serial console), but double-check your model against the page I linked to to be sure...

The two DB25 connectors on top of each other (between the ethernet and keyboard connectors) on your second box are *probably* serial ports, but again check the reference page above. IF they are you will need a gender-changer to plug into them, but they're standard 25-pin serial ports other than that.

> Normally two serial ports would be labeled "A" and "B" -- I don't see that in your photo, so if there's no label on those two stacked ports don't plug anything into them until you've verified what they *actually* are.

---

Now close your eyes and give silent thanks it's not an IPX with the DIN8 connector (which requires a $30+ adapter to plug in to).

Also if your systems have video cards consider getting a 13W3-to-VGA adapter ([they're not too expensive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001I27X5Y)) - it's useful to have around even though my preference for Sun console work is to use the serial console :-)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking it would be much easier to throw in some el cheapo video card (ebay for it) and a keyboard (mice are plugged in into keyboard, at least it was with my Ultra5 I guess I still have somewhere in the house) and do everything "Canst thou not come in by usual way as decent people do? Sir" (c) ... Good luck my friend!